# Wi Fi Direct Connect

Tags: android, android-wifi, wifi-direct

I am using Wi Fi direct for the data transfer in my application. While i am trying to connect to the remote device, it gets a system dialog which says that there is an incoming connection.

We need to manually enter the input whether to accept or decline the connection.

Is it possible to get the handle of that dialog so it can be accepted or declined programmatically.

Any inputs would be much appreciated.